Sending a form with data and a file - react
I have read some threads on the subject but I am not sure if I am thinking correctly.
I'm supposed to create a form where the user enters their details and finally using Drag and Drop adds the file. If all the fields are filled in then he clicks Send and submits the form.
However, I have a problem with Drag and Drop because my component should show a progress bar after adding the file, but the file should not be uploaded yet, only after clicking submit.
Is it ok to handle this file via fileReader?

  const handleFileRead = (file: IFile) => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onprogress = (event) => {
      if (event.lengthComputable) {
        const progress = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
        updateProgress(progress, file.name);
      }
    };

    fileReader.onload = (event) => {
      const fileContent = event.target?.result as string;
      console.log(fileContent);
      updateStatus(FileLoadingStatus.uploaded, file.name);
    };

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file.originalFile); 
  };

I mainly care about the onprogess event and I don't know how to handle it, because event.loaded always returns a value after the file has been uploaded.
Is there any other alternative to displaying this progress?
